# vba get weekday name of date? UK date format issue

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am using the following vba code to get the weekday of a date.

```
Dim strDate
strDate = "01/06/2017"
wStemplaTE.Range("C25").value = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateValue(strDate)))
```

This should produce : Thursday but i am getting Friday.
I think this is because excel thinks my date is US format. Bu It's UK format.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Have you considered changing the string to `01-Jun-2017` to remove confusion?

Comment: @Jeeped in this example StrDate is defined as "01/06/2017" but StrDate is actually linked to another workbook which has and has to have the format like "01/06/2017"

Comment: If it is a real date in a real cell in a real worksheet then use `Range(...).Value2` and get rid of `DateValue`.

Comment: @Jeeped i get a method or object out of range error

Comment: Going forward please put all the crucially relevant information in the question itself. It's a bit frustrating to answer a question only to notice later that the code in the actual question is pretty much completely irrelevant because the "real code" has nothing to do with the code in the question. Comments should contain requests for clarification, not information that completely changes what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Despite being on a MDY regiona;l system, I put `01-Jun-2017` into A1 on Sheet2 and used a custom number format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. Either of these produces the correct weekday name (e.g. Thursday).

```
Debug.Print WeekdayName(Weekday(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value2))
Debug.Print Format(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value2, "dddd")
```

This works because a date can be considered a raw number. `01-Jun-2017` happens to be `42,887`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Dim strDate
> ```

By Hungarian Notation standards you're calling it a `String`, but it's declared as a[n implicit] `Variant`.

```
Dim theDate As Date
```

This declares `theDate` as a `Date`.

For unambiguous date handling, treat dates *as dates*, not as strings - and try to avoid `Variant` whenever you can.

Then use the ISO standard `yyyy-MM-dd` format when you want to assign a *date literal* (using `#` delimiters):

```
theDate = #2017-06-01#
```

That way you don't need to take your `Variant/String` and turn it into a `Date` - *it's already a date*.

```
wStemplaTE.Range("C25").value = WeekdayName(Weekday(theDate))
```

Gives you *Thursday* as it should.

This would, too:

```
wStemplaTE.Range("C25").value = Format(theDate, "dddd")
```

---

*Edit: just read the comments under the question - going forward **please** put all the crucially relevant information **in the question itself***. [@Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584483/1188513) works if there's no date literal, variant or string involved.

Since the date is actually in a cell, and you're writing the weekday name in another cell, I'd suggest an all-Excel approach:

```
=TEXT([theDate],"dddd")
```

Returns the weekday name off the long date format, as text.

There are other approaches too, if you *really* want to work off the `WEEKDAY` - e.g. a lookup table:

[image: index/match lookup using a lookup table]

Make a table somewhere (here I called it `wkDays`), and use the return value of the `WEEKDAY` function to lookup the weekday name.

```
=WEEKDAY([thedate],1)
```

Returns `5` for Thursday.

```
=INDEX(wkDays[Name],MATCH(WEEKDAY([thedate],1),wkDays[WkDay],0))
```

Returns `Thursday` because the `wkDays` table maps `Thursday` to the value `5`.